# JTextField Ignoring a nextLine()?

Tags: java, swing, textfield

Please refer to the most updated post, which is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140395/java-items-not-being-entered-into-the-list-properly), for further comments.

---

So there's this program I'm working on where I'm trying to make the user enter their input through a textbox in a JPanel.

btw, everything worked when I had it taking input from System.in with Scanner. Something about the change involving `textField` that's causing the problem. I have the "main" on another program, so that's not the problem either.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    LinkedList<FoodItem> foodItemList = new LinkedList<FoodItem>();
    CategoryList<String> categoryList = new CategoryList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    protected JButton[] buttons = new JButton[6];
    String[] buttonNames = {"Add Item", "Remove Item", "Search for Item", "Update Item", "Check if List is Empty", "Print Items"};
    String[] buttonCommands = {"add", "remove", "search", "update", "isEmpty", "print"};
    protected JTextField textField;
    public GUI() {
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);
        add(textField);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand(buttonCommands[i]);
            buttons[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
            buttons[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            add(buttons[i]);
            }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(buttonCommands[0]))
            add();
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[1]))
            remove();
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[2]))
            search();
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[3]))
            update();
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[4]))
            isEmpty();
        else
            print();
    }
    public void add()   {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to add.");
        String text = textField.getText();
        try {
            if (foodItemList.containsName(text))
                throw new DuplicateProductException();
            else
                foodItemList.add(enterFoodItem(text));
        }
        catch(DuplicateProductException ex) {
            System.out.println("The product has already been added to the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to update or remove this item? (U for update, R for remove, N for neither)");
            String response = textField.getText();
            if (response.equals("U"))
                update();
            if (response.equals("R"))
                remove();
        }
    }
    public void remove(String s)    {
        if (foodItemList.size() == 1)
            foodItemList.list = null;
        else
            foodItemList.oneBeforeContainingName(s).setLink(foodItemList.oneBeforeContainingName(s).getLink().getLink());
        System.out.println("The product has been removed.");
    }

    public void remove()    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to remove.");
        String text = textField.getText();
        try {
            if (foodItemList.containsName(text))
                remove(text);
            else
                throw new NonexistentProductException();
        }
        catch(NonexistentProductException ex)   {
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to add this product? (Y/N)");
            String response = in.nextLine();
            if (response.equals("Y"))
                add();
        }
    }
    public void search()    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to search for.");
        String text = textField.getText();
        if (foodItemList.containsName(text))    {
            System.out.println("The product is found.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to print it or update it? (P for print, U for update, N for neither)");
            String response = in.nextLine();
            if (response.equals("P"))
                print(text);
            if (response.equals("U"))
                update(text);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
    }
    public void update(String s){
        foodItemList.nodeContainingName(s).setElement(enterFoodItem(s));
    }
    public void update()    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to update.");
        String text = textField.getText();
        try {
            if (foodItemList.containsName(text))
                update(text);
            else
                throw new NonexistentProductException();
        }
        catch(NonexistentProductException ex)   {
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to add this product? (Y/N)");
            String response = in.nextLine();
            if (response.equals("Y"))
                add();
        }
    }
    public void isEmpty()   {
        if (foodItemList.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        else
            System.out.println("The list is not empty.");
    }
    public void print(String s){
        LinkedListNode<FoodItem> temp = foodItemList.list;
        while (!temp.getElement().name.equals(s))
            temp = temp.getLink();
        System.out.println(temp.getElement().toString());
    }
    public void print() {
        if (foodItemList.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        else
            System.out.println("Here is the list:" + foodItemList.toString());
    }
    public FoodItem enterFoodItem(String input) {
        String[] requiredEntry = {"price", "quantity", "description", "size", "special order", "category"};
        double p = 0.0;
        int q = 0;
        String d = "";
        double s = 0.0;
        String so = "";
        String c = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the " + requiredEntry[i] + " of the product.");
            if (i == 0)
                p = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            if (i == 1)
                q = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());
            if (i == 2)
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    d = textField.getText();
            if (i == 3)
                s = Double.parseDouble(textField.getText());
            if (i == 4)
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    so = textField.getText();;
            if (i == 5)
                c = textField.getText();
        }
        return new FoodItem(input,p,q,d,s,so,c);
    }

    public class DuplicateProductException extends Exception    {
        public DuplicateProductException() {;}
    }
    public class NonexistentProductException extends Exception  {
        public NonexistentProductException() {;}
    }
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vendor Interface");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI newContentPane = new GUI();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Sorry it's probably too long (and this is only one program among many in a project...), but to get to the core of the problem, when the buttons come up, I'm supposed to be able to enter the name of the product first. But for some reason it "skips" over not only the name, but also the price. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Please enter the name of the product you want to add.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
Please enter the price of the product.
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.enterFoodItem(GUI.java:150)
    at GUI.add(GUI.java:49)
    at GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:30)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Again, I apologize for the gargantuan post, but I don't know how much of all this I would need to provide you all with enough info to find the bug in this program. Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: `Stacktrace` telling you that you are trying to parse the `empty string` to method `parseXXX()` _(lets say parseInt())_ which causing for `NumberFormatException`

Comment: `add()` might be called before the textfield has a valid value. You can have a default value to the textField to avoid this.

Comment: For better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @Smit - The problem is that it doesn't even let me enter a valid value. It's supposed to take the `String` value `name`, check whether it's in the list, and THEN, if it isn't, ask for the `Double` value for `p`, and so forth. Right now, right after the "Please enter the name of the product you want to add.", even before I can type anything in the textbox, goes straight to `p`, and since nothing is entered there yet, assumes that I'm trying to make a `null String` a `Double`, and prints this error.

Comment: You are mixing console + GUI, is there a reason to do that?

Comment: @porfiriopartida - that's because I was trying to test out the `JTextField` with the `add()` method before implementing it to other methods. Good thing I did, because clearly there are issues with the current program.

Comment: GUI are event drive environments.  Something happens, you respond to it.  Once the user clicks the `Add Item` button, you code is going to run until it finishes the `actionPerformed` method, it's not suddenly going to change states mid run...

Comment: Actually, this is one of the disadvantages of not organize well your code. If you split the real logic from the user interface then you will migrate easier from console to GUI. Now you will have to change a bit of your logic in order to get it work. In order to do so, you must be sure that the state of your inputs are valid. In your GUI you can write .. press buttons in any order, in console based you usually perform commands step by step.

Comment: @2012ssohn: Not sure whats going on exactly without having all code and debug it (that said need [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)). Anyhow before going inside the `for` loop check weather `textfield` is [empty or not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()). Once you done this check go for `loop` and use `else - if` block structure. Look what others are commenting.