# JTextField Ignoring a nextLine()? [Part II]

Tags: java, swing, textfield

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140395/java-items-not-being-entered-into-the-list-properly) for the updated - and better formatted! - version of the question.

---

So this is a follow-up from the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19127402/jtextfield-ignoring-a-nextline). I've taken the suggestion from porfiriopartida and separated the logic from the user interface and put the logic into a separate file called `Simulator`. So here's how the `GUI` program looks right now:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    LinkedList<FoodItem> foodItemList = new LinkedList<FoodItem>();
    CategoryList<String> categoryList = new CategoryList<String>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    protected JButton[] buttons = new JButton[6];
    String[] buttonNames = {"Add Item", "Remove Item", "Search for Item", "Update Item", "Check if List is Empty", "Print Items"};
    String[] buttonCommands = {"add", "remove", "search", "update", "isEmpty", "print"};
    protected JTextField textField;
    public GUI() {
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);
        add(textField);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setActionCommand(buttonCommands[i]);
            buttons[i].setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
            buttons[i].setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
            add(buttons[i]);
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        Simulator helper = new Simulator(textField);
        if (command.equals(buttonCommands[0]))
            helper.add(foodItemList);
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[1]))
            helper.remove(foodItemList);
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[2]))
            helper.search(foodItemList);
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[3]))
            helper.update(foodItemList);
        else if (command.equals(buttonCommands[4]))
            helper.isEmpty(foodItemList);
        else
            helper.print(foodItemList);
    }
    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Vendor Interface");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GUI newContentPane = new GUI();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the `Simulator` program:

```
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class Simulator {
    private JTextComponent tf;
    public Simulator(JTextField textField) {
        this.tf = textField;
    }
    public void add(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi)    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to add.");
        String text = tf.getText();
        try {
            if (fi.containsName(text))
                throw new DuplicateProductException();
            else
                fi.add(enterFoodItem(text));
        }
        catch(DuplicateProductException ex) {
            System.out.println("The product has already been added to the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to update or remove this item? (U for update, R for remove, N for neither)");
            String response = tf.getText();
            if (response.equals("U"))
                update(fi);
            if (response.equals("R"))
                remove(fi);
        }
    }
    public void remove(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi, String s)   {
        if (fi.size() == 1)
            fi.list = null;
        else
            fi.oneBeforeContainingName(s).setLink(fi.oneBeforeContainingName(s).getLink().getLink());
        System.out.println("The product has been removed.");
    }

    public void remove(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to remove.");
        String text = tf.getText();
        try {
            if (fi.containsName(text))
                remove(fi, text);
            else
                throw new NonexistentProductException();
        }
        catch(NonexistentProductException ex)   {
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to add this product? (Y/N)");
            String response = tf.getText();
            if (response.equals("Y"))
                add(fi);
        }
    }
    public void search(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to search for.");
        String text = tf.getText();
        if (fi.containsName(text))  {
            System.out.println("The product is found.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to print it or update it? (P for print, U for update, N for neither)");
            String response = tf.getText();
            if (response.equals("P"))
                print(fi, text);
            if (response.equals("U"))
                update(fi, text);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
    }
    public void update(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi, String s){
        fi.nodeContainingName(s).setElement(enterFoodItem(s));
    }
    public void update(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to update.");
        String text = tf.getText();
        try {
            if (fi.containsName(text))
                update(fi, text);
            else
                throw new NonexistentProductException();
        }
        catch(NonexistentProductException ex)   {
            System.out.println("The product does not exist in the list.");
            System.out.println("Would you like to add this product? (Y/N)");
            String response = tf.getText();
            if (response.equals("Y"))
                add(fi);
        }
    }
    public void isEmpty(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi)    {
        if (fi.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        else
            System.out.println("The list is not empty.");
    }
    public void print(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi, String s){
        LinkedListNode<FoodItem> temp = fi.list;
        while (!temp.getElement().name.equals(s))
            temp = temp.getLink();
        System.out.println(temp.getElement().toString());
    }
    public void print(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi)  {
        if (fi.isEmpty())
            System.out.println("The list is empty.");
        else
            System.out.println("Here is the list:" + fi.toString());
    }
    public FoodItem enterFoodItem(String input) {
        String[] requiredEntry = {"price", "quantity", "description", "size", "special order", "category"};
        double p = 0.0;
        int q = 0;
        String d = "";
        double s = 0.0;
        String so = "";
        String c = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the " + requiredEntry[i] + " of the product.");
            if (i == 0)
                p = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
            if (i == 1)
                q = Integer.parseInt(tf.getText());
            if (i == 2)
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    d = tf.getText();
            if (i == 3)
                s = Double.parseDouble(tf.getText());
            if (i == 4)
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                    so = tf.getText();;
            if (i == 5)
                c = tf.getText();
        }
        return new FoodItem(input,p,q,d,s,so,c);
    }

    public class DuplicateProductException extends Exception    {
        public DuplicateProductException() {;}
    }
    public class NonexistentProductException extends Exception  {
        public NonexistentProductException() {;}
    }
}
```

And when I run the program, right after I press the `Add Item` button, it says "Please enter the name of the product you want to add." (on the console), but even before I can type anything into the textbox, it immediately shows this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Simulator.add(Simulator.java:12)
    at GUI.actionPerformed(GUI.java:31)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's going on this time, and how do I get this fixed?

Comment: That's crazy code, setting a variable to null and then trying to use it.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Your code includes:

```
JTextComponent tf = null;
String text = tf.getText();
```

You can't call a method on a null-valued object. That causes a [`NullPointerException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Maybe you want to get the text from the existing `JTextField`:

```
String text=tf.getText();
```

When you create a new `JTextField` reference with `JTextComponent tf = null;`, you shadow the instance variable with the local variable, making it impossible to access.

EDIT: See Reimus's answer for the other (just as important) thing wrong, in your constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You're shadowing `textField` in the constructor of `Simulator`. replace

```
JTextField tf = textField;
```

with

```
tf = textField;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you used this:

```
public void add(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the product you want to add.");
    JTextComponent tf = null; // tf points to NULL, you might remove this line.
    String text = tf.getText();
```

Your tf reference is set to null, it throws exception right after with:

```
String text = tf.getText(); //null.getText() !!
```

Also here, you are setting the text field to a local variable in the constructor, but the global one is set to null.

private JTextComponent tf;
  public Simulator(JTextField textField) {
    JTextField tf = textField;
  }
Change it to:

```
  private JTextComponent tf;
  public Simulator(JTextField textField) {
   //you don't need "this" but that way you make sure you refeer to the class 
    this.tf = textField; variable.
  }
```

I don't know if that's enough since the code does not compile as is.

- CategoryList class is missing.
- FoodItem class is missing.
- LinkedListNode class is missing.

...

```
public void print(LinkedList<FoodItem> fi, String s) {
    LinkedListNode<FoodItem> temp = fi.list;
```

I don't think there is a guarantee that LinkedList objects are always an instance of LinkedListNode; most likely you should use cast or receive LinkedListNode as argument instead of LinkedList.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's still having the almost identical error of not letting me enter any value though.
btw, how did you know that there's also supposed to be a `CategoryList` class? o_o

Comment: Because I copied your code and it cannot be compiled because I don't have those 3 classes you are referencing there.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about that. It was kind of a placeholder for when I get the implementation ready, wasn't really doing anything in the code yet.